# Итераторы, rvalue и lvalue

Tags: c++

По определённым причинам имеется необходимость реализовать собственный итератор (`Forward iterator`) [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/) сказано следующее:

> Input Can be dereferenced as an rvalue
>
> Output    Can be dereferenced as an lvalue (only for mutable iterator types)

Там же, сказано, что `Forward Iterator` должен включать в себя функциональность `Input iperator` и `Output iterator`. Тогда, каким образом в `Forward iterator` могут присутствовать две реализации `operator*` возвращающие соответственно `value_type` и `reference_type` (`rvalue` и `lvalue`)?

Теперь вопрос: правильно ли я понимаю, что предыдущий абзац моего вопроса - бред, и `lvalue` с `rvalue` - понятия которые определяются (**UPD:** различаются) в зависимости от контекста, и, как следствие, реализация `Forward iterator` будет включать в себя возврат ссылки, которая можт употребляться как `lvalue` так и `rvalue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На cplusplus.com хватает ошибок.

Открываем https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator и https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator и видим, что:

- Forward iterator не обязан быть output iterator'ом (но должен быть input iterator'ом).
- `*a` для input iterator'а должен возвращать `std::iterator_traits<..>::reference`, но этот `reference` можно сделать вообще любым типом (нужно только чтобы его можно было преобразовать в `std::iterator_traits<..>::value_type`.
- А вот у forward iterator'а `reference` должен совпадать с `value_type &`.

Comment: А что насчет того что "lvalue с rvalue - понятия которые различаются в зависимости от контекста"? (Не совсем основной вопрос, но все же хотелось бы выяснить)

Comment: @wcobalt Имеете в виду, что одно и то же выражение, смотря как оно используется, может быть как rvalue, так и lvalue? Насколько я знаю, это так не работает. Всегда можно точно определить value category не глядя на то, как используется выражение.

Comment: Да, но вот вам выражение: `x` - нельзя определить что это, если оно будет стоять справа - то rvalue, слева - соответственно

Comment: @wcobalt Что такое `x`? Если это какой-нибудь `int x;`, то `x` - всегда lvalue. Даже в выражении вроде `y = x;`.

Comment: но в этом выражении оно конвертируется в rvalue, если верить например этой статье: https://habr.com/ru/post/348198/ (раздел: преобразование между lvalue и rvalue)

Comment: @wcobalt Ага, преобразуется. Но до преобразования это lvalue. Имхо, важнее категория до преобразования.

Comment: ответ ошибочный, однонаправленные итераторы предназначены и для записи и для чтения, иначе  не может быть, просто они не являются наследниками  итераторов для записи,

Comment: @ARHovsepyan А разве в ответе написано, что в них нельзя записывать? Там написано, что *не во все* forward iterator'ы можно записывать. (В некоторые - можно, в некоторые, типа `std::forward_list<T>::const_iterator` - нельзя.)

Comment: Получается, что я не правильно понел вас...